# get column name in a query

Tags: php, sql, database

How could i get the column name of an empty record from a table ? For example:

```
SELECT column.name FROM table WHERE id='1111' AND column_name=''
```

It should return every title of an empty column from table.

Comment: I don't get your point, could you precise it please ?

Comment: It can't be done with "normal" sql unless you go wild, very wild for it

Comment: this looks like a bad application design

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Did you mean you want the names of the columns where it is empty? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would do it with php for simplicity's sake, however there might be a sophisticated mysql approach to do this at dbms level

in PseudoCode:

```
$result = MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC ( MYSQL_QUERY( SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='1111' ) )

$blankCols = array();
foreach($result[0] as $key=>$value){
   if($value=="")
   {
      $blankCols[] = $key;
   }
}
```

as i mentioned before, this seems ugly and looks like a bad data structure design.

Answer (score 1):

If you using mysql 5.0+ you can get a table's all column names like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE TABLE_NAME='$table_name'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Note: Chane $table_name to the name of your table's name.

Comment: he only wants the column names for a specific record which are left blank

Answer (score 1):

This is also one method:

```
$mysql_query = mysql_query("describe table");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query)) {
 echo $row[0]."</br>";
}
```